# Xamarin Forms Zxing scan problem with Black Background and White Qr Codes on Andriod Device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, zxing, zxing.net

The problem about Zxing Forms Mobile is cannot scan black background, white color qr code. I've already tried to scan black color qr code,white background and it works.My test device is Android.

I've tried scan white color qr code by using a scanner which i found in play store and it works.So qr code is not bad.

I've tried all the variations in MobileBarcodeScanningOptions.

```
            var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
            {
                UseNativeScanning = true,
                TryHarder = true,
                TryInverted = true,
                AutoRotate = true,
                DisableAutofocus = false,
                UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = false,                         
                DelayBetweenAnalyzingFrames = 150,
                InitialDelayBeforeAnalyzingFrames = 300,
                DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 1000,               
                PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>
                {
                    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                }
            };
```

So Is there anything for solution?

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/194

Comment: @SushiHangover I could not find a solution on this issue.Am I missing something?

Comment: Resolved? An native implementation maybe works better, get a look at mine: https://github.com/AndreaGobs/xam-barcode-scanner

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a frame in the qr, with that it allowed me to scan.

[This work for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAYHn.jpg)

[This dont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34YeH.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).